# how to synchronise 2 async threads / tasks

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database

For my app I have to run two operations, both being asynchronous:

> 1. read from a file ( I use this file to simulate reading from a data bus ) - async operation because I don't know "when" arrive a new
>      message/character on the bus. I search for a specific sequence
>      character, eg frame start_bytes = "xx" and the 4 following bytes are
>      "the data" I wait for.
> 2. read / update data to Firebase, depending on the "data" read from file - async operation due to addValueEventListener use.

I'm thinking a semaphore/mutex mechanism or a simple boolean flag that one task signal to the other one that a new data must be saved/updated to Firebase.

How can I synchronize these two operations ( by embedding them in a Task /  AsyncTask / Thread)?

I ran a search for these topics but I found examples related to UI, ProgressBars and so on .. not really suited/useful to my situation.

read / update data in Firebase

```
   myRefDevices.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                //  addValueEventListener
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    boolean             bChildFound         = false;
                    DatabaseReference   dbrefChildFound;

                    final CDeviceStatus obj_new = new CDeviceStatus();

                    for( DataSnapshot val : dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
                    {
                        if( val.getKey().contentEquals(MAC_ADDRESS[ iIterator ]) )
                        {
                            bChildFound = true;

                            dbrefChildFound = val.getRef();

                            obj_new.setiAvailable_A( val.getValue( CDeviceStatus.class ).getiAvailable_A() + 1 );

                            obj_new.setsID(val.getValue( CDeviceStatus.class).getsID() );

                            dbrefChildFound.setValue(obj_new);
                        }
                    }

                    if(!bChildFound)
                    {
                        Log.d("child=" + MAC_ADDRESS[ iIterator ], "not found");
                    }


                    if(++iIterator == 16)
                    {
                        iIterator = 0;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
```

read from file :

```
try {
    // open input stream text file for reading
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream instream = res.openRawResource( R.raw.simulated_bus );

    //  we convert it to bufferred input stream
    BufferedInputStream bistreamSimulatedBus = new BufferedInputStream(instream);

        try{
            // if we want to stop reading from the file / simulated bus for whatever reason..
            boolean bStayInLoop         = true;

            while ((bistreamSimulatedBus.available() > 0) && bStayInLoop)
            {
                try {
                    // throw new InterruptedException();
                    char c = (char) bistreamSimulatedBus.read();

                    if( COUNT_CHARACTERS_NEWLINE )
                    {
                        if ( '\n' == c ){
                            //  we can count how much NewLine character we have
                            //iNL_Counter++;
                        }
                    } 

                ...

                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException( e );
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
        } 
        finally {
                // release any resource associated with streams
                if ( null != instream ) {
                    instream.close();
                }

                if ( null != bistreamSimulatedBus ) {
                    bistreamSimulatedBus.close();
                }
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let us break the solution like this:

**The basics**

You have two operations : `o1` and `o2`. You want the second operation to execute as soon as the first one has completed.

It **clearly** appears to me that you need an `event-driven` solution here.

**Approach**

Using the concept of `Publisher/Subscriber` design pattern, you can make the `Initiator` of `o1` be the `Publisher` of an event. Then, when this particular operation `o1` is completed, let the class (activity, fragment, service) `notify` the other class which we will call `Subscriber`.

**Code**

Add the following line to your `build.gradle (app-level)`:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, simply create a simple `Plain Old Java Object (POJO)` that represents your event.

```
public class RequestCompletedEvent{ // add constructor and anything you want}
```

Next, to `Publish` the event, you simply call the `post(POJO instance)` like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new RequestCompletedEvent(true));
```

Then, finally, in the `Subscriber` class, simply listen for notifications by adding the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Then still within the same class, use the `Subscribe` annotation to catch any signals:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(RequestCompletedEvent event) {
   /* Do something */
   //trigger the second operation here;
  startOperationTwo();
}
```

**Summary**

It would help to note here that the easiest way to pull this off is to use an `async` task (AsyncTask sub class) to read your files, then when successfully done, inside `onPostExecute()`, you can notify the `Subscriber` to initiate the next operation.

I hope this helps; and good luck! Let me know if you need further assistance!